# Integrating in Mathematica

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have the following function

```
f1 = 8/(3 - r) + 6 (-1 + dt) r + (8 r)/(3 - r)^2
```

Then I try to integrate `f1/r` 
I expect to have

```
Integrate[f1/r, {r, r1, 1}] = - Integrate[f1/r, {r, 1, r1}]
```

but I get two different results with the following conditions:

```
0 < Re[r1] < 1 && Im[r1] == 0
```

my result

```
Integrate[f1/r, {r, r1, 1}] is not equal - Integrate[f1/r, {r, 1, r1}]
```

Could you please tell me where I have made the mistake or nature of this problem?
  === gives me Fals. which means that they are not equal

```
g2 = Integrate[f1/r, {r, 1, r1}, 
  Assumptions -> 0 < r1 < 1 && dt ∈ Reals]
```

gives me

```
(2 (3 (-1 + r1) (7 - 9 dt + 3 (-1 + dt) r1) - 
   8 r1 ArcTanh[1 - (2 r1)/3] + r1 Log[16] - 
   12 Log[-((2 r1)/(-3 + r1))]))/(3 (-3 + r1))
```

and

```
g1 = Integrate[f1/r, {r, r1, 1}, 
  Assumptions -> 0 < r1 < 1 && dt ∈ Reals]
```

gives me

```
(2 (21 - 9 dt (-3 + r1) (-1 + r1) + r1 (-30 + 9 r1 + 25 Log[4]) - 
   25 Log[64] - 50 (-3 + r1) Log[3 - r1] - 
   54 (-3 + r1) Log[-(2/(-3 + r1))] + 12 Log[r1] - 
   4 r1 Log[r1]))/(3 (-3 + r1))
```

still I don't know why?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. You seam to have inverted the domain of the integral. Plus, is that equal sign meant to be an equation to solve?

Comment: yes I have inverted the  domain of the integral, but the result  of integrals are not the equal. and my question is why>

Comment: The indefinite integral, `Integrate[f1/r, r]` is `8/(3 - r) + 6 (-1 + dt) r + (8 r)/(3 - r)^2` which is complex for `r == 1` and contains branch cuts.  Therefore, results differ depending on where `r1` is in the complex plane.

Comment: You can use also `Assumptions`: `Integrate[f1/r, {r, r1, 1}, 
 Assumptions -> 0 < r1 < 1 && dt \[Element] Reals]`.

Comment: After performing the integrals as suggested by @corey979, you will find that the two solutions look different.  However, using `FullSimplify` will show that they are the same.

Comment: @ bbgodfrey They are not the same yet!!!

Comment: ff2 and f1 are the same

Comment: during copy and past I made mistake, I am not using several symbols.

Comment: FullSimplify[g2] === FullSimplify[-g1] then I get false

Comment: @ corey979  Thanks Solved :)

Comment: There's a difference between [`SameQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SameQ.html) (`===`) and [`Equal`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Equal.html?q=Equal) (`==`).

Comment: @corey979 your method is very good and convincing, but why if I do what I told you and put 
 
FullSimplify[g2] == FullSimplify[-g1]  Mathematica does not give me answer?

Comment: It gives a correct answer. The two are not in general the same, but they are equivalent under the prevailing assumption that `0<r1<1`. Other comments and responses have indicated this and it would be a good practice to read them carefully.

Answer (score 3):

```
f1 = 8/(3 - r) + 6 (-1 + dt) r + (8 r)/(3 - r)^2

int1 =  Integrate[f1/r, {r, 1, r1}, Assumptions -> 0 < r1 < 1 && dt ∈ Reals]

int2 = -Integrate[f1/r, {r, r1, 1}, Assumptions -> 0 < r1 < 1 && dt ∈ Reals]

int1 == int2 // FullSimplify[#, 0 < r1 < 1] &
```

> True

Answer (score 2):

```
f1[r_] = 8/(3 - r) + 6 (-1 + dt) r + (8 r)/(3 - r)^2 // FullSimplify;

int1 = Assuming[{Element[r1, Reals]},
  Integrate[f1[r]/r, {r, r1, 1}]]

(*  ConditionalExpression[
   6*(-1 + dt + r1 - dt*r1 + 
        (1/(9*(-3 + r1)))*
          (2*(-3 + 4*(-3 + r1)*
                  ArcTanh[1 - (2*r1)/3] - 
                r1*(-3 + Log[4]) + 
                Log[64]))), 0 < r1 < 1]  *)

Assuming[{0 < r1 < 1},
 Integrate[f1[r]/r, {r, r1, 1}] == -Integrate[f1[r]/r, {r, 1, r1}] // 
  Simplify]

(*  True  *)

int2 = Assuming[{Element[r1, Reals]},
  -Integrate[f1[r]/r, {r, 1, r1}]]

(*  ConditionalExpression[
   -6*((-1 + dt)*(-1 + r1) + 
        (1/(9*(-3 + r1)))*
          (2*(3 - 4*(-3 + r1)*ArcTanh[
                    1 - (2*r1)/3] - 6*Log[2] + 
                r1*(-3 + Log[4])))), 
   1 < r1 < 3]  *)

Assuming[{1 < r1 < 3},
 Integrate[f1[r]/r, {r, r1, 1}] == -Integrate[f1[r]/r, {r, 1, r1}] // 
  Simplify]

(*  True  *)
```

Combining the two regions

```
Simplify[(int1 // Normal) == (int2 // Normal),
 0 < r1 < 1 || 1 < r1 < 3]

(*  True  *)
```

The regions both border `r1 == 1`

```
Limit[int1, r1 -> 1, Direction -> 1]

(*  0  *)

Limit[int2, r1 -> 1]

(*  0  *)
```

Combining the regions

```
Simplify[(int1 // Normal) == (int2 // Normal),
 0 < r1 < 3]

(*  True  *)
```